# Does it cost more gas to use =, >, <. operators with bytes32 than it does with uint256?

Tags: solidity, gas, bytecode

Does it cost any gas to cast a bytes32 memory value to uint256? What is the assembly op code for this?

Does it cost more gas to use =, >, <. operators with bytes32 than it does with uint256?

Spreadsheets about gas costs say it cost 3 gas for =, >, < operations, so is that true with all types that support those operators? Or is the gas cost for these operators different depending on the type?

I tested some of these things in remix and got mixed results -- sometimes it cost more gas, sometimes less.

Does it make any sense to cast bytes32 to unint256 for doing an operation like this: require(uint256(myvalue) != 0);

If you know the answers to these, can you please tell me how you know?

Comment: I'm fairly confident they're the same, but you're saying you've found something different in your testing. You'll need to share the code you used and your methodology for testing it before anyone can help explain your results.

Comment: I was not able to find any indication in the yellow paper either, that there should be a difference in gas cost by casting as you mentioned, can we see the code?

Comment: Both uint256 and bytes32 should cost the same, the cast should cost nothing since the EVM operates only on 32 bytes data and have no types. But it really depends on the code generated by the compiler. You can compare bytes32 with an uint constant but cannot compare with a variable of type uint256.